# BPMN plugin not installing

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jbpm, redhat-bpm

I am using Eclipse  Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2).when i am trying to install JBPM i am getting"
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JBoss jBPM Core Developer Resources 7.5.0.Final (org.jbpm.eclipse.feature.source.feature.group 7.5.0.Final)
  Missing requirement: JBoss jBPM Core 7.5.0.Final (org.jbpm.eclipse.feature.feature.group 7.5.0.Final) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss jBPM Core Developer Resources 7.5.0.Final (org.jbpm.eclipse.feature.source.feature.group 7.5.0.Final)
    To: org.jbpm.eclipse.feature.feature.group [7.5.0.Final] 
installation stopped

"

and trying to install JBPM and BPMN2.0 modeler,
when i try to install                 http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/oxygen/1.4.x/ i am getting

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BPMN2 Modeler - jBPM Runtime Extension Feature 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1 (org.eclipse.bpmn2.modeler.runtime.jboss.feature.group 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1)
  Missing requirement: org.eclipse.bpmn2.modeler.core 1.3.3.Final-v20170221-1647-B60 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.transaction 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: BPMN2 Modeler Core 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1 (org.eclipse.bpmn2.modeler.core 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.transaction 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BPMN2 Modeler - jBPM Runtime Extension Feature 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1 (org.eclipse.bpmn2.modeler.runtime.jboss.feature.group 1.4.2.Final-v20171109-1930-B1)
    To: org.eclipse.bpmn2.modeler.core 0.0.0
```

I tried different versions and also tried to install plugin from market place and also tried to install jars manually,but no luck. my colleges who are  using the same version of eclipse are able to install plugin with no issues.Suggestions are welcome,Thanks.

Comment: The install can't find the `org.eclipse.emf.transaction` plug-in. Make sure you have 'contact all update sites to find required software' option checked in the 'Install New Software' dialog.

Comment: Hi,Yes i did check the option before installation